# extracting methods from the base class in c# in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to extract base class methods to derived class in visual studio.

example : ActionFilterAttribute is the base class but i am not able to extract the methods in visual studio. anyone can help out

Comment: What do you mean by `extract`? Are we talking reflection or that you simply can't access its methods?

Comment: Are You deriving from some class and trying to access it's base class methods? Are these methods marked as public/protected or as private? If it is the 1st group, You should be able to call them, but if they are private You would need to use reflection (or better avoid that completely).

Comment: actually this is not about reflection. i think it is simple question.i am  deriving from some class and trying to access it's base class methods and it is like extracting methods from interface using visual studio. is it clear?

Comment: The base class methods are just available in your derived class. They do not show up/get implemented in your derived class like they do when implementing an Interface.